# Постановочное представление "Мальчик, изменивший мир"

Tags: запятые

Скажите, правильно ли стоит запятая?

Comment: надо ли ставить запятую после слова мальчик

Answer (score 3):

Надо, Витя, надо.

Это ж причастный оборот, стоящий **после** определяемого слова.